# LG-P990 (2x) Australian, upgrade to ICS or latter

Tags: updates, lg-optimus-2x

I have an LG-P990 (Optimus 2x) Australian, is there an official upgrade to ICS or latter available? If so how do I get it and do the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade your phone to official LG's ICS release do the following (remember to backup all your important data before starting):

1. Go to official LG support page for your region, [Downloads & Manuals section](http://www.lg.com/au/support/software-manuals)
2. Scroll down to **Search by keyword** and input this: `Optimus-2X-P990`, click the only
   result.
3. Scroll down to **Downloads**
4. Click the tab **Software Update**
5. Follow *carefully* all the instructions there.